# Unable to Use created partitions

Tags: mount, drive

I have formatted my system and created drive as in the screen , while try to use 329gb folder not able to use it like create any folder copy file from my documents and anything.Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tejbj.png)

Comment: You have to format as ext4 (or other Linux format), create mount point, mount partition and give yourself ownership & permissions to use that mount. Post this: `lsblk -f` Data can be same drive or another drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: after provided permission it works, thanks